# Convoluted relative pronoun sentece structure

Tags: relative-pronouns

> sentence:
>   There is a common European myth to which both authors referred subconsciously in the books in question.

How can I split this sentence into two? There is a common European myth. Both authors referred subconsciously to in the books in question. I don't understand this sentence structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core part of the sentence is

> There is a common European myth to which both authors referred.

You could split this as

> There is a common European myth. Both authors referred to it.

Where "it" means "this common European myth.

The rest of the sentence tells us *how* and *where*:

> There is a common European myth. Both authors referred to it [subconsciously] [in the books in question].

The preposition "to" has been moved with the relative pronoun to observe the rule "the pronoun goes before the noun". If you choose not to follow this rule you get the equivalent sentence

> There is a common European myth, which both authors referred to subconsciously in the books in question.

Which is correct, has the same meaning, but is slightly less formal in style.